# unzip: gives: checkdir error: .../directory exists but is not a directory

Tags: bash, cygwin

My team produces a build.zip file using windows that I want to do some post processing on using cygwin/bash script, unzipping it, and then doing further processing.

I can use the Windows 7 GUI "Extract All" and everything works fine -- extraction works, getting into the "problem directory" is no problem.  Everyone has been doing that for ages.

The directory it is complaining about contains .obj and .md files.  In a bash shell I can go to it and list it and all is good (list it after Windows extracted it).   But using the unzip command, I can't extract this part of the build.zip.   I get the following error (and the preceding success before it):

```
  inflating: bld_731/build_20150731/GVII/Software/_bld/rel/tcf/TscControlFmtCtrl.obj
  inflating: bld_731/build_20150731/GVII/Software/_bld/rel/tdl.exe
  checkdir error:  bld_731/build_20150731/GVII/Software/_bld/rel/tdl exists but is not directory
                 unable to process build_20150731/GVII/Software/_bld/rel/tdl/.
       ...

 checkdir error:  bld_731/build_20150731/GVII/Software/_bld/rel/tdl exists but is not directory
             unable to process build_20150731/GVII/Software/_bld/rel/tdl/CmfCmd.obj.
```

As you can see, it's both the directory and the files it finds inside the directory.

Do you know how to resolve this?   Do I need to go another extraction utility, perhaps ??   Thanks.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: removing the linux tag, because it's specifically **not** matching the problem.

Comment: This is tools used directly for programming.  I'm trying to use unzip in a bash script and it is failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with Cygwin.  It interprets the existence of "tld.exe" as "tld" also existing.     unzip is probably just using a standard stat call to check if  "tld" already exists and check if it is a directory.  stat is probably saying yes "tld" exists (because "tld.exe" exists)

```
touch testfile.exe
if [ -f testfile ] ; then echo y ; else echo n; fi
```

On a normal linux type system you would expect the above to answer 'n'.  However on cygwin, the result is 'y'.

This is part of cygwin's mechanism to allow windows .exe files to be executed without the .exe in the command.

See: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-exe

Comment: ... shoot, so is there no way to unzip this file then?

Comment: try using the 7z command to extract the files.  (it knows how to extract .zip files)  This doesn't seem to have this issue.  In the cygwin installer, select the  "p7zip" package under the "Archive" category.   Command to extract is   "7z x myfile.zip"

Comment: Thanks.  Trying, keep getting "unable to get setup.ini from <the mirror I pick>.  I think sometimes my company blocks stuff and sometimes they don't, unless you know what this error is

Comment: Something is blocking the cygwin installer from getting its setup file.  Possibly you need to select one of the proxy settings on the screen before the mirror list?

Comment: Thanks, I tried IE5 settings and it didn't help.   What do I put in for the Proxy Host if I "Use HTTP/FTP Proxy:"?

Comment: This is getting beyond the scope of the original question... but not sure what the proxy settings (if needed at all) would be for your company.    Sometimes specific security settings can prevent a program from accessing the network.  Some other things to try:   Make sure the setup.exe is on a local disk (not a network share), is not in a temp folder, and from the Properties windows (right click on the setup.exe and select Properties) click the Unblock button if it exists and is not grayed out.

Comment: Thanks.   It is in my downloads directory and is unlocked.  It's a laptop so I'll bring it home on my internet tonight and "getter done!"  ;-)  Thanks for all the help.  I will comment here tomorrow on whether the 7z command works.  THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP, MUCH APPRECIATED.

Comment: Going home to my network didn't solve it.  I think the setup file gets corrupted somehow at times, as when I downloaded a new one, everything worked fine -- getting the package.  I'm about to try it now to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `maven install` in a git bash environment. I solved it by manually creating the directory next to the `*.exe` file. The `mvn install` then unzipped my artifact without issue. In your case, simply go to the target directory and do `mkdir tdl`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative command to extract the archive is 'jar' (Part of the Java JDK) e.g., 'jar xf file.zip'